# jquery slide an element up and down on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to slide an element down when another is click and if that link is then clicked again, slide the element back up, is there a cleaner way of doing it than this?

```
$("#dropdown, #dropdown span, #dropdown dt a").click(function(event) {
            $("#dropdown dd").slideDown(defaults.speed);
            $("#dropdown").addClass('drop_down_open');
            event.preventDefault();
        });

        $(".drop_down_open, .drop_down_open span, .drop_down_open dt a").click(function(event) {
            console.log("hello");
            $("#dropdown dd").slideUp(defaults.speed);
            event.preventDefault();
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#anElement").click(function(e) { 
    var theItem = $("#dropdown dd");
    if (theItem.css("display") == none) {
        theItem.slideDown(defaults.speed);
    }
    else {
        theItem.slideUp(defaults.speed);
    }
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Modify according to your specific needs.

Comment: Many thanks, however this code, opens the element on click, but then immediatly closes it again as display is no longer = to none.

Comment: That shouldn't happen - it's an if-else statement, so if you are only running it one time per click, it should work properly. Are you adding so many selectors it's running several times per click? Put an alert("hello") in there and check.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you wanted. http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/